# How can one detect an active WebRTC connection on the Mac programmatically?

Tags: mac, browser, script, webrtc

What would be the cleanest way to infer that a WebRTC connection is either being established or is active.

e.g. maybe there is a way to query the browser, or can one tell by actively monitoring connections?  (Can one even detect UDP traffic?)

So far I've been looking at `netstat -atp tcp` but I can't see any pattern yet which  could be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the article
[How do you find the current active connection in webrtc-internals?](https://testrtc.com/find-webrtc-active-connection/)

Here is a summary for Chrome and for a simplified example :

- Open `chrome://webrtc-internals`.
  The active candidate pair will be shown in bold and may have been
  renamed to `Conn-audio-1-0`.
- Expand this to see the candidates
- The `googActiveConnection` is true for the currently active connection
  and false for all others.
- The active connection is defined by the local and remote specified
  in the `localCandidateId` and `remoteCandidateId` fields.
- You may now examine their attributes.

You will find much more details and screenshots in the article.

Comment: Even though this is a great answer, I don't know if this is scriptable, and/or would also translate to other browsers.

Comment: See [this article](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/new-tool-debugging-webrtc/) for Firefox.